# Returning value from apps script (doPost) to client, after calling an external API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch, bruno

I am trying to invoke an apps script deployed web app (doPost method) and get a response back to the client app (this could be HTTP client like Postman/Bruno or simple javascript app).
The deployed web app would call an external API and return its result.
When I try this I am getting a message (HTML) saying "The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type."
If I do not call external API and try to return a default / hard coded object from doPost, the client is getting the response properly (as a JSON).
Console log statements are showing proper output values
Please suggest if there is a way out.

Deployed web app (apps script) is

```
let respout= { "jokeid": 0, "errcode": 0, "errmsg": "na" };
function doPost() 
{
    console.log('inside doPost func', respout);
    try 
      {  //If tried to return above respout with out executing "jokefun()", below statement works with client
         //return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(respout)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
         return jokefunc().then( res => {
                                          respout={ "jokeid": res.id,"errcode": 200,"errmsg": "success" };
                                          console.log('resp out val in then func',respout);
                                          return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(respout)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
                                        })
        
      } 
    catch (error) 
      {
        console.log('Exception in doPost', error);
      }
    
}

async function jokefunc() 
{
  try
    {
      const API_URL = "https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke";
      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_URL);
      const responseText = response.getContentText();
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseText);
      console.log('Fetch called', jsonData);
      return jsonData; // Return the fetched data object
    }
  catch(error)
    {
      console.error('Some thing went wrong',error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried by removing the async and called in a synchronous way in the doPost and it worked like a charm.

Comment: If you have a solution people might benefit if you share it. Otherwise consider closing the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).